Is it possible to redirect excluding the basename?
I have set a basename to my router e.g.:
const router = createBrowserRouter(routes, { basename: '/app' });

Then in my root loader I have something like this:
export async function() {
  const session = await get(session);

  if (!session) {
    return redirect('/login');
  }

  return session;
}

redirect('/login') gets me to /app/login as it should but I am trying to send my user to /login instead.
/login runs on a different app by the way.

return redirect('/login');

Is basically a shortcut for:
return new Response("", {
  status: 302,
  headers: {
    Location: "/app/login",
  },
});

You can try specifying the full URL or return a Response object and set an absolute path from the origin.
Examples:
return redirect(`${window.location.origin}/login`);

return new Response("", {
  status: 302,
  headers: {
    Location: `${window.location.origin}/login`,
  },
});

